# Token Authentication/Authorization With PassportJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm currently in the process of developing a Node/Express-based API for an application that will be distributed on multiple platforms. Because of this, I will need to authenticate/authorize users based on a token rather than sessions/cookies.

After doing some research, I've found that PassportJS is a great plugin for accomplishing something like this. Unfortunately, after going through its documentation for several hours, there doesn't seem to be any good explanation of raw token-based authentication.

I don't want to use any plugins such as JWT -- just Passport, Express, and MongoDB.

How would I go about implementing a token-based user authorization system with Passport. I need explanations on token generation, token passing, and the rest of the process.

Please answer this in a clear and concise manner, as if you're explaining  to a 5th grader.

Thanks :)

Comment: why don't you want to use a library for token generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try and break down your question into a few parts:

- Configuring Passport
- Where to use Passport
- Miscellaneous final remarks

First, a slight misconception. Passport doesn't come bundled with a token generation system. Passport is designed to be configured with strategies that you have to include as dependencies. This is done so Passport itself can be light and modular. I might need to authenticate with Twitter when you need a local (username and password) authentication strategy. So, Passport includes neither. I install what I need and keep the package size light.

TL;DR: There's no way of not installing a plugin for Passport. You need to include a *strategy* of some kind.

I'm going to assume you want to use a local strategy. So, you need **passport-local**. Don't worry, it was written by Jared Hanson, the author of Passport.

Most everything I use will be from the Passport docs, specifically [here](http://passportjs.org/docs/username-password).

Let's look at configuration:

- Install Passport and the **passport-local** module.
- Make sure Express, MongoDB, Node, npm, etc. are up to date.

The basic configuration file for passport-local looks like this:

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username: username ), function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Now you need to place a form on a web page. Here is a very basic example:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
    </div>
    <div>
         <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Next, you need a route in your Express app. See the [Express Routing Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router) for more info on how this works.

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                     failureRedirect: '/login' })
);
```

Note on parameters: By default, **LocalStrategy** expects the credentials to be in parameters named *username* and *password*. There are configuration options to name them otherwise, for instance logging in with email rather than a username.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Looking at the code, I don't think that this could handle tokens, or am I wrong here? Does this example rely on sessions or cookies?

Comment: Yeah, if this answers your question it would be awesome if you select it as the answer. If it doesn't, is there anything else you have a question about?<br> Edit: Sorry, I somehow missed the last half of that comment. *passport-local* does use sessions. If you want to use tokens you will need another strategy. Let me edit the answer to accommodate tokens.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a token based authentication strategy -- and how so?

Comment: Very good response by the way, I'm just looking to implement this with an iOS app -- and sessions/cookies won't work for that.

Comment: So, are you building a react-native app?

Comment: I'm building one using the Ionic Framework. So essentially, I want a token-based API to handle requests on the backend.

Comment: Then, you have three options (that I know of): *passport-jwt*, *passport-accesstoken*, and *passport-unique-token*. Unless you really hate JWT, that's what I would go with. I have no idea how the other two are getting tokens and the whole security of tokens relies on their randomness and lack of intersection. If you aren't careful you'll end up with an MD5 situation.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how far along are you? If you are just starting the project, I would look into the feathersjs framework. It comes bundled with Passport configured with all of the most popular strategies (local, OAuth, OAuth2). To clarify: I'm not affiliated with feathers in any way. It's just treated me well.

Comment: Interesting, I've gotten to the point of creating the registration system -- and that's it. I'll do some more research. Thanks!